# WordPress - Update all existing posts at once

Tags: posts

Is there a way to cycle through all existing, published posts on a WP site, that will replicate pushing the "update" button on every post one by one? This would be a one time event. I have a site with thousands of existing posts and there is no way I can go through and hit "update" on every single one of them.

I've added a plugin that will display some new info on each post, but in order for it to work on existing posts, you have to "update" every single post individually.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean actually you want to change something in all post?

Comment: It sounds like you should be filtering the post content using the `post_content` filter, rather than actually updating the post content. If I installed a plugin and it went and edited every one of my posts I wouldn't be happy. Also, cycling through every post on the site is potentially a slow process and is very likely to time out on large sites or on shared hosts.

Comment: You can also update all posts via Admin area if your server have the power to list them all. List all post, change settings of listing post to a value that list all of your post. Now select all via the checkboxes on the left side and update all posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try running [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) on all posts concerned. It will trigger the `save_post` hook.

According to the Codex:

> Unlike wp_insert_post(), it is only necessary to pass the ID of the
>   post to be updated and the elements to be updated.

You could try looping an array of post IDs and running the function on them. You can fetch the post IDs using WP_Query.

```
foreach( $posts_id as $post_id ){
    wp_update_post( $post_id );
}
```